# Choppy transform with CSS filter on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, pug, stylus

I'm doing a hover effect that increases the images brightness and scales the image on hover state. For some reason the transform seems to choppy with the CSS filter. Any idea why this makes the transform choppy? Seems to be working smoothy on Safari and Firefox.

Basically I'm doing this:

```
.parent
  width 300px
  height 300px
  overflow hidden
  img
    transition: all 1s ease-out
    transform: translate(0px, 0);
    filter: brightness(80%)
    &:hover
      transform: scale(1.1)
```

See full demo here: http://codepen.io/tzzo/pen/MmKeVm

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean the blur that appears during the transition, or are you getting low framerate on it?

Comment: Works the same for me in firefox and chrome - do you have any plugins in your chrome browser that may be disrupting it?  I would disable all your plugins and retry just to make sure

Comment: you may take a look at `will-change` ,  it might help

Comment: Same choppiness on freshly installed Chromium, so I don't think any plugin etc. is causing the problem. It looks like the img is a bit moving while transforming.

Comment: `will-change` didn't help :( I added a second a img to the pen without filter which works fine on my Chrome.

Comment: Is your hardware accelerantion on? If you want more information about hardware acceleration and how you can change it in google chrome follow [this link](https://www.lifewire.com/hardware-acceleration-in-chrome-4125122)

Comment: My chrome W7 has the same choppy effect but i did not trigger the hardware acceleration (conflicts with my video card)

Comment: @GCyrillus ok, thanks. I'm pretty sure the lack of hardware acceleration is causing my problems also with this implementation.

Comment: else, you can take a look at mix-blend-mode for a work around :  example from your pen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OmMbvo  some infos about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Comment: @GCyrillus Nice, that runs smoothly! Too bad the support for mix-blend-mode isn't that great :(. https://caniuse.com/#search=mix-blend-mode

Comment: chrome can be targeted http://browserhacks.com/ but it is an average work around a tiny bit too tricky to my taste ;)

Comment: @GCyrillus Yup, super patchy :D Maybe I'll try something adding a mask to the img and adjust the opacity on hover or something. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a lightweight and well supported implementation.

I ditched CSS filters and decided to use `opacity` instead. If the background of the image doesn't work well with the you have to set it separately.

```
img
  background-color: black
  opacity: 0.8
  transition: all 3s ease-in-out
  &:hover
     opacity: 1
     transform: scale(1.1)
```

Added working solution to my pen: http://codepen.io/tzzo/pen/MmKeVm

Answer (score 0):

Just had a look at the codepen on Chrome 56 and it's really smooth for me. However, if you want to increase the image brightness on hover you need to add the filter to the hover too:

```
img:hover {
  -webkit-filter: brightness(100%)
  filter: brightness(100%)
}
```

Comment: Hi! Yes the brightness was missing for a minute while I was debugging. Not a solution to the problem though.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. Maybe check it on https://www.browserstack.com it's working like a charm for me ✌️

Answer (score 0):

use this code in hover proerties-

```
.parent img:hover {-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);  -o-transform: scale(1.1);  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);  transform: scale(1.1);  opacity: 1.0;  filter: brightness(150%);}
```

Comment: Hi! Sorry, but this didn't help :D

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the issue on my machine but I have had this problem at other times

You could try triggering hardware acceleration on the element by adding transform3d

```
.parent
  width 300px
  height 300px
  overflow hidden
  img
    transition: all 1s ease-out
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0)
    filter: brightness(80%)
    &:hover
      transform: scale(1.1) translate3d(0,0,0)
```

Note you need to re-apply the translate when you alter the transform in the hover rule